# Password protecting mamp:localhost

Tags: apache, localhost, mamp

I've created a .htpasswd file and .htaccess to password protect my localhost. I have put both in my mamp folder (where my website folders are). I have encrypted the password put in my htaccess :

```
AuthUserFile /WorkArea/mamp/
AuthType Basic
AuthName "localhost"
Require valid-user
```

It has locked me out of my localhost by giving me a 500 internal error.

Comment: What is the colon (`:`) doing in that path?

Comment: Also make sure that the http server can acutally _read_ that file.

Comment: sorry colon isn't in my file, just the path to the file. Also I've gone in terminal and have written chmod 0644 .htaccess chmod 0644 .htpasswd

Comment: Also when I inspect the files it says Everyone Read only

Comment: Sure, I see that the colon is not inside your file. But it certainly should also _not_ be inside your path. What kind of path is that? It might also be that you have to enclose that path in double quotes (`"`). BTW: any entries in the http servers error log file?

Comment: no it's not in my path either and I didn't put quotes around the path. Would that be necessary? Sorry where can I find that file?

Comment: That colon not in your path? Then why do you specify it in your path above? And what file are you looking for? Don't say the `.htpasswd`! You wrote you created it and you refer to it in your `.htaccess` file. The file must be located where that path points to. And yes, you probably need double quotes around that path. Didn't you take a look at examples and the documentation?

Comment: This was in my apache error log: [Tue Apr 29 16:09:54 2014] [alert] [client...] /WorkArea/mamp/.htaccess: Invalid command '{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf1038\\cocoasubrtf360', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: The example I worked from didn't have double quotes and also wrote the file in the path :S  http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/

Comment: What do you mean by "wrote the file in the path"? And let's get this clear: please post the real path to your `.htpasswd` file and the real content of your `.htaccess` file. There is no security risk in that, since no one knows your ip address here. I have the feeling there is some really fundamental misunderstanding here...

Comment: I've updated my question to have the path. I've tried removing .htpasswd from the path and it is still giving me the error. I've tried putting it in double quotes aswell

Comment: That means you have `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` in the same place, so where you store your published documents? Don't, that is a security risk. The password file should _not_ be within the folders published by the http server. This is _not_ the issue here, but important nevertheless.

Comment: Ah, and now I understand your error! You probably used a word processor to create the `.htaccess` and/or `.htpasswd` file! Please use a plain text editor instead, so that really only the text content is inside the file, not additional formatting and font informations! As an alternative you can try to use a function "Save as plain text" or similar if your word processor supports that. But for programming it is _always_ better to use a plain text editor.

Comment: Ok, I summed up the discussion into an answer below. Feel free to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

The discussion above fed to this solution:

It is important to understand that `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files have to be plain text files to work. So the best way to create and manage them is to use a plain text editor. Using some kind of word processor (like OpenOffice-Word or similar) will save additional formatting information into those files. This will lead to the http server not being able to make sense of those files, thus throwing an error.

Also some side note: the `.htpasswd` file should *not* be placed alongside the documents pubished by the http server. This is a high security risk. So `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` style files must be stored at completely separate locations, the first within, the second outside the area of the documents.